# C++ Unable to connect two objects

Tags: c++

I havent touched c++ in quite a while and was trying to make a red black tree template when I ran into this problem. I want to add an element and just cout the thing. But when I switch functions, Im unable to have the same RBT variable. It changes as becomes an entirely new variable. Ive no idea why this doesnt work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "redblacktree.h"

using namespace std;

int menu();
void addElement(RedBlackTree<int> RBT);
void peak(RedBlackTree<int> RBT);

int main()
{
    int option=-1;

    RedBlackTree<int> RBT;

    while(option != 99)
    {
        option=menu();

        switch(option)
        {
        case 1:
            addElement(RBT);
            break;
        case 3:
            peak(RBT);
            break;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    int option;

    cout<<"1. Add element"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Peek"<<endl;

    cin>>option;
    cin.ignore();
    return option;
}

void addElement(RedBlackTree<int> RBT)
{
    int value;
    cout<<"Enter element: "<<endl;
    cin>>value;
    cin.ignore();

    RBT.insert(value);
    //cout<<RBT.printRoot()<<endl; //works
}

void peak(RedBlackTree<int> RBT)
{
    cout<<RBT.printRoot()<<endl; //does not work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass by reference:

```
void addElement(RedBlackTree<int> &RBT);
void peak(RedBlackTree<int> &RBT);
```

This doesn't create a copy of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you pass `RedBlackTree<int> RBT` into `addElement()` and `peak()`. By C++'s pass-by-value nature, the instance are copied before passing into the functions. Thus, the functions work on a temporary copy.

To make the functions work on the instance passed in, you should pass the parameters by reference. In this case, pass `RedBlackTree<int>&` into `addElement()` and `peak()`.

Also, since you said that your `peak()` didn't work, you should check whether your copy constructor is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass by reference, because you're modifying an object by adding a new element.

In your solution, in the end of the addElement, RBT is simply destroyed, because it acts like a local variable and goes out of scope.